# Nunjacks icon count macro

Tags: javascript, html, templates, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks and want to create a macro that plus in star icon and then in the template I can just specify how many stars each element has: e.g:

```
{{star(4)}}
```

will display for icon star:

rating: ****

rating: *****

At the moment I don't know how to pass the count:

```
{% macro starIconTables( star ) %}

    {% for star in stars %}
        <span class="icon icon-star-filled"></span>
    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range`:

```
{% macro stars(num) %}
{%- for i in range(0, num) -%}<span class="icon icon-star-filled"></span>{%- endfor -%} 
{% endmacro %}

stars: {{ stars(4) }}
stars: {{ stars(10) }}
```

P.S. `{%-` and `-%}` to remove additional line breakers.